# Command Prompt Net Beans

Tags: netbeans

I would like to know if it is possible to use the Console Command Prompt with Netbeans for the purpose of input similar when working with Microsoft Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can do inputs from the console NetBeans will offer you. Why do you want to use separate console Command Prompt ?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the NetBeans console, but I agree - it can handle basic I/O just fine.

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to know how to input command line arguments but I got it now.

Comment: @Arianule No need to say sorry. I was just asking if you have any specific purpose to use Console Command Prompt with it. You can accept answers here if you find helpful.